# How to pass an object as data throw angular router navigation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a route like that.

```
this.router.navigate(["/menu/extra-hour/extra-hours/observations/", id])
```

These work well but I want to pass apart the complete object of data in the screen to render it calling the route.

How can i do that?

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can send it as a parameter, or you could consider creating a service that holds the data for you, and then retrieve it with that id, after the navigation.

Comment: You can keep the data in a service or NgRx, and get the data with id when your component needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing data objects through routes is not a good practice. My suggestion is pass such data through the common service or BehaviorSubject(rxjs).

btw if you want to some how pass the data through routes here is the way

In current component you have to set the data to route like bellows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form1',
  templateUrl: './form1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form1.component.css']
})
export class Form1Component {
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  handleButtonClick() {
    const myObject = { name: 'John', age: 30 };

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        data: myObject
      }
    };

    this.router.navigate(['/list'], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

Then you have to access the data inside the target component `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
    const currentState = this.router.lastSuccessfulNavigation;
    console.log(currentState?.extras)

  }
```